# ReactJs: Control flow in nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component `A(bigger container)` which calls two other components `B(say a kind of header)` and `C (input form)`. Now I need to hide show header given user behavior on C.

I have a solution where A passes functions as props to C, which C can call and change the state in A. This modified state is passed to B, which changes the text in B.

Minimal viable example:-

**A: Contains state with `focused` and call B and C components**

```
class A extends React.Component {
  state = {
    focused: true,
  }

  onFocus = () => {
    this.setState({ focused: true });
  }

  onBlur = () => {
    this.setState({ focused: false });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <C onFocus={ this.onFocus } onBlur={ this.onBlur } focus={ this.state.focused } />
        <B focus={ this.state.focused } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**B: Simply show different text based on props from A**

```
const B = (props) => (
  props.focus ? <div> Focussed </div> : <div> Blurred </div>
);
```

**C: Contains input textbox, which execute functions from A on user action**

```
class C extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text"
        value={ this.state.value }
        onChange={ this.handleChange }
        onFocus={ this.props.onFocus }
        onBlur={ this.props.onBlur }
        focus={ this.props.focus }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

However in my real application I have multiple components between A and C (A calling A1 calling A2...), and to make these functions available all intermediate components have to receive them as props.

Is there a neater way to solve this requirement without having my each intermediate components having receive these props (meant to only pass further)?

Comment: If you end up having a lot of of [prop drilling](https://blog.kentcdodds.com/prop-drilling-bb62e02cb691), it might be worth looking into a state management solution like [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) or [Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux).

Comment: maybe react context

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko I have read about context api, but I am unable to form example of that. Could you please help me with that.

Comment: @Tholle Is there a possibility to solve this without redux? It's dependency which I can't propose to have only for this use case. Btw I am reading the link you provided

Comment: Check out this article, [Pass Multiple Children to a React Component with Slots](https://daveceddia.com/pluggable-slots-in-react-components/?utm_campaign=0731slots#use-children-to-pass-props-directly)(section  `Use Children to Pass Props Directly`), which gets around `prop drilling` problem. Gist is that, you pass components that already holds props and containers simply display them as children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to form an example for solving the above problem using context. Set the context in the higher level component in our example A.

```
const ConveyorBelt = React.createContext();
class A extends React.Component {
  state = {
    focus: true,
    onFocus: () => {
      this.setState({ focus: true });
    },
    onBlur: () => {
      this.setState({ focus: false });
    },
  }

  render() {
    const { focus } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ConveyorBelt.Provider value={ this.state }>
          <C />
        </ConveyorBelt.Provider>
        <B focus={ focus } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now any component directly or indirectly beneath A can read the values we pass from A. In our case C can read A values as

```
const C = () => (
  <ConveyorBelt.Consumer>
    { (context) => (
      <input
        onBlur={ context.onBlur }
        onFocus={ context.onFocus }
        autoFocus={ context.focus }
      />
    ) }
  </ConveyorBelt.Consumer>
);
```

Now we can change the text in B which we wanted using A state.

```
const B = (props) => (
  <div>
    { props.focus ? 'Focused' : 'Blurred' }
  </div>
);
```

There can be as many components between A and C and there is no need to pass props to all of them. Only C can read the data passed by A which solves the problem of props drilling.